# Replace Node in Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a function that needs to replace a node of a specified value in the list (old), and replace that node with a new value specified by the user (new). This is what I've come up with, but it makes my program stop working so something's wrong with what I've conjured up.

```
node *modifyNode(node *L, int old, int new)
{
    while (L != NULL)
    {
        if(L->val == old)
        {
            L->val = new;

        }
    }
    L = L->next;
}
```

Comment: `L = L->next;` move into while-loop.

Comment: Or do it all with `for (; L; L = L->next) if (L->val == old) L->val = new;` If you are replacing a *single* value, you can add a `break` within the `if` to prevent needlessly iterating after the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position of the `L = L->next;` should be in the loop

```
 node *modifyNode(node *L, int old, int new)
 {
     while (L != NULL)
     {
       if(L->val == old)
        {
          L->val = new;

        }
      L = L->next; // this should be position to refer next node in the loop
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

new is a keyword in c++, can not be used as a variable name

```
 node *modifyNode(node *L, int old, int _new)
 {
     while (L != NULL)
     {
       if(L->val == old)
       {
          L->val = _new; //new is a keyword

       }
       L = L->next; //reposition this here
     }
}
```